# How to get Unique value of subarray?

Tags: php, arrays, string, array-unique

Actually, I am getting array and subarray. I want to get the unique values from the subarray. I tried many things but it is not working for me. Here is the array value of mine

```
  Array
(
    [title] => Array
        (
            [0] => Cake Shops,Food,Inexpensive Restaurents,Moderate Restaurants (Rs.400 - Rs.800),Multicuisine Restaurants,Pure Veg Restaurants,Restaurants,Cake Shops,Food,Inexpensive Restaurents,Moderate Restaurants (Rs.400 - Rs.800),Multicuisine Restaurants,Pure Veg Restaurants,Restaurants,Cake Shops,Food,Inexpensive Restaurents,Moderate Restaurants (Rs.400 - Rs.800),Multicuisine Restaurants,Pure Veg Restaurants,Restaurants,Cake Shops,Food,Inexpensive Restaurents,Moderate Restaurants (Rs.400 - Rs.800),Multicuisine Restaurants,Pure Veg Restaurants,Restaurants,Cake Shops,Food,Inexpensive Restaurents,Moderate Restaurants (Rs.400 - Rs.800),Multicuisine Restaurants,Pure Veg Restaurants,Restaurants,Cake Shops,Food,Inexpensive Restaurents,Moderate Restaurants (Rs.400 - Rs.800),Multicuisine Restaurants,Pure Veg Restaurants,Restaurants,Cake Shops,Food,Inexpensive Restaurents,Moderate Restaurants (Rs.400 - Rs.800),Multicuisine Restaurants,Pure Veg Restaurants,Restaurants,Cake Shops,Food,Inexpensive Restaurents,Moderate Restaurants (Rs.,,
            [1] => Bakery,Cake Shops,Caterers,Bakery,Cake Shops,Caterers,Bakery,Cake Shops,Caterers,Bakery,Cake Shops,Caterers,Bakery,Cake Shops,Caterers,Bakery,Cake Shops,Caterers,Bakery,Cake Shops,Caterers,Bakery,Cake Shops,Caterers,Bakery,Cake Shops,Caterers,Bakery,Cake Shops,Caterers,Bakery,Cake Shops,Caterers,Bakery,Cake Shops,Caterers,Bakery,Cake Shops,Caterers,Bakery,Cake Shops,Caterers,Bakery,Cake Shops,Caterers,Bakery,Cake Shops,Caterers,Bakery,Cake Shops,Caterers,Bakery,Cake Shops,Caterers,Bakery,Cake Shops,Caterers,Bakery,Cake Shops,Caterers,Bakery,Cake Shops,Caterers,Bakery,Cake Shops,Caterers,Bakery,Cake Shops,Caterers,Bakery,Cake Shops,Caterers,Bakery,Cake Shops,Caterers,Bakery,Cake Shops,Caterers,Bakery,Cake Shops,Caterers,Bakery,Cake Shops,Caterers,Bakery,Cake Shops,Caterers,Bakery,Cake Shops,Caterers,Bakery,Cake Shops,Caterers,Bakery,Cake Shops,Caterers,Bakery,Cake Shops,Caterers,Bakery,Cake Shops,Caterers,Bakery,Cake Shops,Caterers,Bakery,Cake Shops,Caterers,Bakery,Cake Shops,Caterers,Bakery,Cake Shops,Caterer,,Bakery,Cake Shops,Caterers
            [2] => Home Delivery Restaurants,Home Delivery Restaurants,Home Delivery Restaurants,Home Delivery Restaurants,Home Delivery Restaurants,Home Delivery Restaurants,Home Delivery Restaurants,Home Delivery Restaurants,Home Delivery Restaurants,Home Delivery Restaurants,Home Delivery Restaurants,Home Delivery Restaurants,Home Delivery Restaurants,Home Delivery Restaurants,Home Delivery Restaurants,Home Delivery Restaurants,Home Delivery Restaurants,Home Delivery Restaurants,Home Delivery Restaurants,Home Delivery Restaurants,Home Delivery Restaurants,Home Delivery Restaurants,Home Delivery Restaurants,Home Delivery Restaurants,Home Delivery Restaurants,Home Delivery Restaurants,Home Delivery Restaurants,Home Delivery Restaurants,Home Delivery Restaurants,Home Delivery Restaurants,Home Delivery Restaurants,Home Delivery Restaurants,Home Delivery Restaurants,Home Delivery Restaurants,Home Delivery Restaurants,Home Delivery Restaurants,Home Delivery Restaurants,Home Delivery Restaurants,Home Delivery Restaurants,Home Deliv,,Home Delivery Restaurants
            [3] => ,,,Chocolate Manufacturers,,Chocolate Manufacturers,,Chocolate Manufacturers,,Chocolate Manufacturers,,Chocolate Manufacturers
            [4] => ,,,Chocolate Manufacturers,,Chocolate Manufacturers,,Chocolate Manufacturers
            [5] => 
        )

)
```

All i want is to get unique data from it and remove the blank value

i tried it like

```
for($i=0;$i<count($listing);$i++){
        $tags['title'][$i] = $listing[$i]->cat_title;
        $tags['taa'] = array_unique($tags['title'][$i]);
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($tags);
    echo '</pre>';
```

In `$listing` i am getting data from db.

Comment: can you please give an example of the output you want ? I'm not sure to understand exactly what you want. Also please add a `var_export($listing);` (will output something we can re-use to test our own code based on your data)

Comment: What is the `$listing` contents

Comment: Your code will give you the unique values for the last array item, change `$tags['taa']` to `$tags['taa'][$i]` to create array for each `title` element